# How does item repair work?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm trying to understand how repairing items works in Divinity: Original Sin. It seems like I just need a repair hammer and a low level in blacksmithing to repair higher-level items any time I like with no negative effects, which seems too easy, especially since durability seems to be the main mechanism for preventing brute-forcing through every chest and door. So, to make sure:

1. What, exactly, is required for fixing an item?

   - In terms of equipment needed, skills needed, etc.
   - And what is the precise dependency on item level / value / type / whatever
2. Is there any potential downside to fixing an item too often or too little?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two thing for repairing an item:

- You need a character that has invested points of blacksmith and /or
  has equipped items that give a some points in that skill.
- You need a repair hammer or a tong in that same character. Both of
  them can be bought, looted or found somewhere often.

Then you may right click an item in the blacksmith character inventory and select "Blacksmithing" in the menu that appears to repair the item. Alternatively, if you want to repair a item in another character inventory panel, you can right click the repair hammer or tong in the blacksmith character inventory and select "Use" (double click also work). This will change the cursor to an anvil. Then click in the damaged item in another another character inventory to repair it.

There *used to exist* a potential downside on fixing an item: It losed maximum durability permanently unless you had 5 or more points in blacksmith, but, at the time of the current answer, it looks like that is no longer true. Also, It used to require higher ability levels depending on how much damage the item has sustained, but I cannot find any instance of that being applicable anymore at the current game version, but I'm still at low level, so If anybody can confirm or refute it, please do it in the comments so I can update the answer acordingly.

Anyway, even when that was applicable, people used brute force anyway to open chests and doors. They simply resorted to spells, summons or unbreakable weapons to do so.

Comment: Wait, so is it crafting you need, or blacksmithing? And are you positive that the more damaged the item is, the higher the skill required? And is the item level irrelevant?

Comment: @Oak It is blacksmith, corrected the answer. As per the level requirement, it used to be true, but I cannot confirm it in my own game. I have only 1 character with blacksmith, level 3, but can repare items of any level I can got my hand onto at the moment (~level 12) no matter how damaged they are, so I will remove it from my answer too.

Comment: As of breaking chest, I find it interesting to keep a high level weapon in your inventory to do so.
They have more durability, deal much more damage, and the only downside, which is the AP cost, doesn't apply to breaking a chest.